# Dynamic typesafe remapping of compound enum like const objects in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, mapped-types, conditional-types

I am working on a little utility that would produce typesafe remapped object/types of compound enums. By compound I mean here that the enum (const object really) key maps to object instead of a numeric or literal value.
Here is the [playground with code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzHArgOwCYCUIGM4BOGAPACoB8UAvFDvkcQNYQhwBmUpANLXoSc1YdSAbUHtOAXR6jxwyWJYTZS+ZPLkA3AFgAUHr340AZ2BQIaFAgDSLAHIBDBNBoByACTvBrnbtCQoWxAAeTYAUUsEADUHABsUCDJKGjlORSEpPX9oINCIqyDqKGyJCwL7Jwgs8ByWUKSi3PDIwoAfQLrmqxj4xIoDXQgAD2QCMyNTKAIIBAcwfIQAGQBLZiLiPSgtznMh4AsMYygAbwBfLk3tgElC4f3MI6aki91tqGDbvYPHzue9cgAFJctmVnAQHAAjWIQABcnBeb2WaCCcJuLAR21QwBR7yCLwAlNRKMdLhMzNNZmBIBgFkVghCAFZ4YAAOjYBEQEWABGWEGMQNebygAPpTNwrIs3N5-NBEHBUIghIcRwAggRwSBiOllDJtWpyPiWZSAQD0jwAG5xBKSQlUYkDIXbabAFAENBQERIwpUH3mFoVZxQAD8UEEUDhlt6nuRLCgyo6IS60StfXI0igWO9vtBQUcgZDYYjKZEmdj8aaCx6CSSkkkvkdp3xl3xvkuztd7opc2ptPjOEpPciK2YAH0RwB3ZZgMg8NEgHgfFiUAD0y-73YgNKHqyqulOrd0q6gYA5CoQGY4AAs4OPinBjxzIARYiAoBhlmw2HLJcsHPsoBCEDAOOEAWFAAAsUC4MqfLCp4YYANRQPBsbtChr5ISecBgFA7RYThSHobhD7YVAmGPk2h7LlAABUUDLEcABEDhoCAjHFJe0CAZM2HAMscDupx0xBtUATrlSm4LMOfS7PchywIgyDoNgfAMCxIDkLOnxyT8ibPLisZ3N8Cb1P0ujJFAc6ycZFb+q+IaLq+RkPCZSaFCGxwiNY9HuqkpCSHC1inOGJyXF5PmhqoUhwqI1gKI5dZ6MFcKOdZLm2eU9lbCSgrhUikUZLFChzrWgW+MloW5d5+V+V5xVBKVaRxSICXlQMonQOJg5WNJY6TtOpBpfJ8BIKgmB0PwxDqZplnaTZvwUAuc3pQt5D-EUOVbHlvlRYN8ZFSIJUBU18UNW1+iDCMhDjAJkyLCqdgAOIAKoqo9YQjjAwQACJhBtlwqgAYnCxzHnAxjLHxAlwgADDwDFwPAGCwlArgOGwrgWimcKuCq7KrA4LHGJjUDOMADg43jPKMITJiuFA5wAwAsiDYMQ1DaBwgAjPDxiI3AyM404JORgklMIJeDg8rgJNkxTqOAAVIgDYSIAtEiANlI9OM4KKpYKzyDs-xnNQAATLz-OC6jUsi9jqNqpCywyzwcs44AnGCAIxggAUYIAkmCaxiq4sgHlwAFoABIjqQADqIPAmzkOG9zMOmzHCNIyjrgAF6XgAtJHmMx6LacwJeSJ8tAAKkOC74c3E+J54KWzO6jgC0coA4aauJcWtbEHz16+DcfQ1AXMwwAzGbqc4+nKDW70ONByg8Sy0B8uuHPC8M0lcZHGSUDGH+DFsNKvD0CQlymDyaAAOYYqD+v90bkSAQQmj0Xz4871Kl-PwXcJn0iF-P43X+l917mQGNvW+HNSBwCuHzIoXZ5jbmYACe6T1XrvU+j9MIPBXAQMNiTVwKcBYQFcJRbewwuZFFwQJKBMC4AiBhpIKAR50ZgNumYOWUCqwuCmDMOYUkdzIIei9N6H0vq-WwXLfBBcSGGDYbsY2RQOFwC4SIVw7tvauEYUeO2EIHasJMGYQQnCUxwN4QgnqAiUHCPQWIrBqN0JSJTDI3QZChjDyKEY5RKYWRAyYdRYw1554YAAtAKmBMib6MmJ470PDKT8KQVYtBojMHYIcakrwLBnGuMgikFgxjeg+MBn4negTYjBMAlAIGQA) and code:

```
type CompoundRecord<T> = Record<keyof T, Record<keyof T[keyof T], T[keyof T][keyof T[keyof T]]>>;


const enumKeyName = '$$key';
type KeyOfEnumValue<T> = keyof T[keyof T]
type KeyOfEnumKey = typeof enumKeyName
type KeyOf<T> = KeyOfEnumKey | KeyOfEnumValue<T>

export const remapEnumLike = <
    T extends {},
    IKey extends KeyOf<T>,
    OKey extends KeyOf<T>,
>(
    enumerable: T,
    inKey: IKey,
    outKey: OKey,
) => {
  const remappedEnum = Object.fromEntries(
      (Object.entries(enumerable) as Array<[keyof T, T[keyof T]]>).map(([key, value]) => {

        return [inKey === enumKeyName ? key : value[inKey as KeyOfEnumValue<T>], outKey === enumKeyName ? key : value[outKey as KeyOfEnumValue<T>]];
      })
  );

  return remappedEnum as RemappedEnumLike__wip<T, IKey, OKey> //RemappedEnumLike
};

// problem of how to properly differentiate between 4 cases
// * is "any" the best option here?
type RemappedEnumLike<T extends CompoundRecord<any>, IKey extends KeyOf<T>, OKey extends KeyOf<T>
> = IKey extends KeyOfEnumKey ? OKey extends KeyOfEnumKey ? {[K in keyof T]: K} : {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K][OKey];
} : OKey extends KeyOfEnumKey ?  {
  [K in keyof T[K][IKey]]: K;
} : never

type RemappedEnumLike__wip<T extends CompoundRecord<any>, IKey extends KeyOf<T>, OKey extends KeyOf<T>
> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K][IKey]]: T[K][OKey];
}

export const LANGUAGE_CODE = {
  AF: { position: 0, isoCode: 'af', value: 'Afrikaans', meta: 'Afrikaans' },
  AM: { position: 1, isoCode: 'am', value: 'Amharic', meta: 'አማርኛ' },
  AR: { position: 2, isoCode: 'ar', value: 'Arabic', meta: 'عربى' },
  //...
  ZH_TW: {
    position: 102,
    isoCode: 'zh-TW',
    value: 'Chinese (Traditional)',
    meta: '中文'
  },
  ZU: { position: 103, isoCode: 'zu', value: 'Zulu', meta: 'Zulu' }
} as const satisfies Record<
  string,
  { position: number; isoCode: string; value: string; meta: string }
>

const positionToIso = remapEnumLike(LANGUAGE_CODE, 'position', 'isoCode')
const ex1 = positionToIso[0] // af

const metaToValue = remapEnumLike(LANGUAGE_CODE, 'meta', 'value')
const ex2 = metaToValue['عربى'] // Arabic

const keyToValue = remapEnumLike(LANGUAGE_CODE, '$$key', 'value')
const ex3 = keyToValue.AF // should be Afrikaans

const keyToKey = remapEnumLike(LANGUAGE_CODE, '$$key', '$$key')
const ex4 = keyToValue.AF // should be AF
```

I would appreciate the help with how to properly narrow down conditional type so it match to only one part of the union `KeyOfEnumValue<T>` and not the other `KeyOfEnumKey` so I can reliably differentiate between 4 possible states (+ eventual `never` state). Right now even with providing input and output different that `$$key` I land in `{[K in keyof T]: K}` case. `__wip` type shows that it really works with dynamic passed properties.

Is `CompoundRecord<any>` only option to reliably allow myself to access `IKey/OKey` in `T[K][IKey/Okey]`?

Also, I would value any feedback or improvements on how to make it more reliable, compact or if there is some more meaningful way :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Making heavy use of [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as), you can cover all 4 cases like this:

```
type RemappedEnumLike<
    T extends CompoundRecord<any>,
    IKey extends KeyOf<T>,
    OKey extends KeyOf<T>
> = IKey extends "$$key"
    ? OKey extends "$$key"
        ? { [K in keyof T]: K }
        : { [K in keyof T]: T[K][OKey] }
    : OKey extends "$$key"
    ? { [K in keyof T as T[K][IKey]]: K }
    : { [K in keyof T as T[K][IKey]]: T[K][OKey] };
```

Here are some example calls:

```
const positionToIso = remapEnumLike(LANGUAGE_CODE, "position", "isoCode");
const ex1 = positionToIso[0]; // "af"

const metaToValue = remapEnumLike(LANGUAGE_CODE, "meta", "value");
const ex2 = metaToValue["عربى"]; // "Arabic"

const keyToValue = remapEnumLike(LANGUAGE_CODE, "$$key", "value");
const ex3 = keyToValue.AF; // "Afrikaans"

const keyToKey = remapEnumLike(LANGUAGE_CODE, "$$key", "$$key");
const ex4 = keyToKey.AF; // "AF"

const valueToKey = remapEnumLike(LANGUAGE_CODE, "value", "$$key");
const ex5 = valueToKey["Afrikaans"]; // "AF"
```

[Playground (with full code)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzHArgOwCYCUIGM4BOGAPACoB8UAvFDvkcQFBQtQDWEIcAZlKQDTNWdQiQ5depANriefALr8+MznNLyVE5bMnz55RuQDcjRvjQBnYFAhoUCANKcAcgEME0GgCIAJD-FeJqCQUE4gAPLcAKJ2CABqrgA2KBBklDQ62qq6QeDQYZEx9mHUUMEQcrbFLu4QuSEF3GmljUWOnFAAPqGchbEJyakUJowQAB7IBNbmVlAEEAiuYG0AMgCWHKVMrHw2Y8C2GBZQAN4AvoI7AJIl4weYx41pl6zht-uHj71NFIYAFEIWFUPARXAAjRIQABcfBeLDWaDCMJunDhUFQwCRUDenEYAEpqJQToCoDNrPNFmBIBg2qVwmCAFZ4YAAOm4BEQMWABDWEAsAJ2Oz+9KZuFZtm5vP5wIgoIhEAJrmOAEECKCQMRNGolNJMup9HiWZSBYLTX9NEoAG5JFLyAlUIkk02m+bAFAENBQKRO52+hElKiBmyxMJuDw+32RqAAfnYuKjCdYMOtgyk-o6Sp6EWi-RtQ3IigjifRKExHUDNGBodqReLrFj4lrdagybzUgxJUzrVzgzShebUHkJkTZyLeJJeJGO1d7s9FKW1NpmZwlMXsXWHDIShRICUOJAxkYZxG5VoCwXEBp642qRJpD29yOsEQyHQ2DwomIrjQB7RO4fnxZpEzwkvuAEPEBPwGOkUD-ncgG+P4nBeCSsZgfBEGIQERaxicXoOFACJxlo6gwgRo6+jCeFSARRF6vIMLSA4Gj7vIUAUUm2LvI+xxYchqGnPhhGenqUCZkxGg7noZHsSSVFCXR2S7OJNGSWE0nKMxUisexIzjJM0xwJY1grMqzgAOIAKrKuZUQAPowOEAAiUSlMSOzKgAYvJyAWGswBrEZMIAAxKGsFhwPAGDQlAXiuNwXhWnmMJeMq7IbK434WIlUAeMArgpWlPJsJllheOxaLKgAsj5cB+QFQVQAAjGFEVRTFcUIDlKYpIVCAABauDyuA5XlBWxYABUiANhIgC0SIA2UjlRcJLKlgtX1YFaAwgATK1kVwNFKVDd1yWxaq4JrCNShjSlgCcYIAjGCABRggCSYItaIAPRvSyX0kgAWgAEnZpAAOpUUWvn+RtMJNcFO1FuFe0HbFABe-UALTA4lRY9R1MD9QifLQH8pCghgENGUkeKY7612xYAtHKAOGmVOsEtOw-ZZa1k5tzXBQAzLt7UpUjKDHYMKU-SgySjRA+VixLwsVUeYnHGSUAWK4AUWNwUpnvQJAklYPJoAA5mieHgw1XOxGCspGIRbX7TFBsIkbtvYzCTvG7bNMe0bsmHmYRmzObG2kHAVwRaU87LNeHB-KZFnWbZDnOVESheMHRk5V48PtV4k4B8ZexNaUGdoKH4dwFIwVDlAH2xfFKEF7MY2hwMKSR+e0f2BuEBx2ZVk2fZjkuWnY1Z9jecmCr4xbaULdwG3EBSF493PV4Nd16lcoXY3KviK3eYd5Sqw3n3CeD8nI+xX4ARpxP+fT2MPOlPvC95iyXm25vRUZVlu+B9YV+AY5idxPrHeOA8k7D1TtfJCIAs432Qg-ABewAAsL9OChzCB-TyX83qnU8v-Qu2MsHlhAcfGOvcIGJyHinO+eYEFwMnk3aw4wACspQSFwDCMvH+JU-4b3walQhjAgA)